# Scrapy find words that dont exist in website

Tags: python, scrapy

Im writing a Scrapy spider that should find if a particular string exists in the websites content (text). I have many websites (couple of thousands) and many strings that need to be found, so that why I'm using lists bound to variable in the code. Some lists are imported from other python files.

Problem Im having is that the code seems to be generating a positive "hit" even though after inspecting the URL manually with dev tools I cannot find the string in the URL. Here's the code and example of result.

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor
from scrapy.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from list_loop import *
import re
 
word_to_find = 'pharmacy'
 
 
class TestSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = 'test'
    # these are lists of a lot of domains imported from another
    # file called list_loop.py
    allowed_domains = strip_url
    start_urls = merch_url
 
    rules = (
        Rule(LinkExtractor(), callback='parse_item', follow=True),
    )
 
    def parse_item(self, response):
        # Here I clean up the parsed text not to include /n or whitespace.
        words = response.xpath("//a//text()").getall()
        cleaned_words = [word.strip() for word in words]
        cleaned_words = [word.lower() for word in cleaned_words if len(word) > 0]
 
        # Then I loop through the cleaned_words in order to find a match
        for single_word in cleaned_words:
            re.search(r'\b%s\b' % word_to_find, single_word)
            yield{
                'Matching': 'Found the word {} in {}'.format(word_to_find, response.url)
            }
        else:
            pass
```

The `allowed_domains` and `start_urls` lists have alibaba.com inside them along with many other sites. After running the spider I got such a result output:

```
{"Matching": "Found the word pharmacy in https://www.alibaba.com/?from_http=1"},
{"Matching": "Found the word pharmacy in https://www.alibaba.com/?from_http=1"},
{"Matching": "Found the word pharmacy in https://www.alibaba.com/?from_http=1"},
{"Matching": "Found the word pharmacy in https://www.alibaba.com/?from_http=1"},
{"Matching": "Found the word pharmacy in https://www.alibaba.com/?from_http=1"},
{"Matching": "Found the word pharmacy in https://www.alibaba.com/?from_http=1"},
{"Matching": "Found the word pharmacy in https://www.alibaba.com/?from_http=1"},
{"Matching": "Found the word pharmacy in https://www.alibaba.com/?from_http=1"},
{"Matching": "Found the word pharmacy in https://www.alibaba.com/?from_http=1"},
{"Matching": "Found the word pharmacy in https://www.alibaba.com/?from_http=1"},
{"Matching": "Found the word pharmacy in https://www.alibaba.com/?from_http=1"},
```

The same happened with many other sites that didn't actually have the word 'pharmacy' in the contents or HTML. Any ideas what is wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you are missing an if statement. Here in your code you are yielding that sentence whether there is a match or not.

```
    for single_word in cleaned_words:
        re.search(r'\b%s\b' % word_to_find, single_word)
        yield{
            'Matching': 'Found the word {} in {}'.format(word_to_find, response.url)
        }
```

I believe you wanted something like this:

```
    for single_word in cleaned_words:
        if re.search(r'\b%s\b' % word_to_find, single_word):
            yield{
                'Matching': 'Found the word {} in {}'.format(word_to_find, response.url)
            }
```

Comment: Glad to know. Please accept my answer by clicking the checkmark.